# What does "issued XXX and YYY shares" mean?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, financial-literacy, shares, balance-sheet

I'm looking at a random company, Hain Celestial Group (HAIN). Their [10-Q](http://services.corporate-ir.net/SEC/Document.Service?id=P3VybD1hSFIwY0RvdkwyRndhUzUwWlc1cmQybDZZWEprTG1OdmJTOWtiM2R1Ykc5aFpDNXdhSEEvWVdOMGFXOXVQVkJFUmlacGNHRm5aVDA1T0RnNE5qTTNKbk4xWW5OcFpEMDFOdz09JnR5cGU9MiZmbj1UaGVIYWluQ2VsZXN0aWFsR3JvdXBfMTBRXzIwMTQxMTA3LnBkZg==) from 2014-11-07 says on the first page: "As of November 3, 2014 there were 50,460,313 shares outstanding of the registrant’s Common Stock, par value $.01 per share."

But their balance sheet says "Common stock - $.01 par value, authorized 100,000,000 shares, issued 51,970,721 and 51,575,743 shares"

Does this company have 50M shares outstanding or 102M shares? What does "issued 51,970,721 and 51,575,743 shares" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**authorized 100,000,000 shares**

They cannot issue shares more than that so 102M isn't possible.

> Common stock - $.01 par value, authorized 100,000,000 shares, issued 51,970,721 and 51,575,743 shares

If you look at the right 2 columns it become clear what it means. You missed the `$` symbol and on the top `(In thousands, except share amounts)`

> ouststanding share 51,970,721 -> 520

On Sept 30, 2014 outstanding shares * 0.01 and rounded off to arrive at 520.

> ouststanding share 51,575,743 -> 516

On June 30, 2014 outstanding shares * 0.01 and rounded off to arrive at 516.

Comment: That was so obvious once you pointed it out, thanks!